# Dafny inductive lemma: cannot infer postcondition of induction hypothesis

Tags: induction, dafny

I am trying to define the small-step semantics of a very simple language with arithmetic expressions (source code available [here](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/vA5Y)). For the sake of simplicity, we assume that the language only allows literals and the unary minus (`-exp`).

```
datatype expression = Literal(int) | Minus(expression)
```

I have defined a relation `e1 --> e2` specifying how to perform a step of computation from the expression `e1` to obtain the expression `e2`. Let us just assume for simplicity that this relation always holds:

```
predicate Step(exp: expression, exp': expression) { true }
```

(Any other nontrivial relation would also lead to the problem I describe here).

Now I define a relation `e1 -->* e2` specifying that `e1` can be reduced into `e2` after zero, one, or more steps of computation (as in [R. Leino's paper on extreme predicates](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/well-founded-functions-extreme-predicates-dafny-tutorial/), pg. 11):

```
inductive predicate StepStar(exp: expression, exp': expression) {
    (exp == exp')
    || (exists exp'': expression :: Step(exp, exp'') && StepStar(exp'', exp'))
}
```

I would like to prove that the `-->*` is closed under contexts. That is, that  `e -->* e'` implies `Minus(e) -->* Minus(e')`. This can be proved by induction on the derivation of `-->*`:

```
inductive lemma StepStarContext(exp1: expression, exp3: expression)
    requires StepStar(exp1, exp3)
    ensures StepStar(Minus(exp1), Minus(exp3)) 
{
    if (exp1 == exp3) {
        // Base case: zero steps.
    } else {
        // Inductive step.

        // We unfold the exp1 -->* exp3 relation into: exp1 --> exp2 -->* exp3.
        var exp2 :| Step(exp1, exp2) && StepStar(exp2, exp3);

        // Apply induction hypothesis on exp2 -->* exp3.
        StepStarContext(exp2, exp3);

        // ASSERTION VIOLATION: 
        // Why Minus(exp2) -->* Minus(exp3) cannot be proved?
        assert StepStar(Minus(exp2), Minus(exp3));
    }
}
```

Dafny cannot prove the last assertion, although it should follow from the postcondition application `StepStarContext(exp2, exp3)`. If I comment out that assertion Dafny can prove the lemma successfully (in fact, Dafny can still prove it when its body is empty), but I am still intrigued by the fact it cannot prove this assertion. Am I missing something?

I have also derived the prefix lemma as described in Leino's paper (see [source code](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/well-founded-functions-extreme-predicates-dafny-tutorial/)). Strangely, Dafny does not only prove this assertion in the prefix lemma, but also in the inductive lemma `StepStarContext`. Why?

Any help would be appreciated.

*Dafny version*: 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized that the inductive lemma is desugared as follows:

```
lemma StepStarContext#[_k: ORDINAL](exp1: expression, exp3: expression)
  requires StepStar#[_k](exp1, exp3)
  ensures StepStar(Minus(exp1), Minus(exp3)) 
{
  if (exp1 == exp3) {
     ...
  } else {
    ...
    // Apply induction hypothesis on exp2 -->* exp3.
    StepStarContext(exp2, exp3);

    // ASSERTION VIOLATION: 
    assert StepStar#[_k - 1](Minus(exp2), Minus(exp3));
  }
}
```

Basically, the unsatisfied assertion asks the length of `exp2 -->* exp3` to be `_k - 1`, but this does not follow from induction hypothesis, since the conclusion of the lemma says
that `Minus(exp1) --> Minus(exp3)` for *some derivation length*. So, in the induction hypothesis, we cannot expect `exp2 -->* exp3` to be of length `_k - 1`.

After fixing the assertion as follows,

```
assert exists k' :: StepStar#[k'](Minus(exp2), Minus(exp3));
```

Dafny gives the go-ahead.